# Convert mysql query to Laravel's DB:Query Builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I tried this on database using SQL tool. It's working perfectly. But Now i Am struggling to Implement it to my DB: query Builder.Any help or suggestions will be grateful for me. If more details need please comment..I will follow next

```
SELECT u.*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(22.559648)) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lng`) - radians(88.415552)) + sin(radians(22.559648)) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS distances 
FROM users AS u
JOIN locations AS l ON `u`.`location_id` = `l`.`id` 
HAVING distances < 32.688888 
ORDER BY distances DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JinalSomaiya
I changed following things and work fine.

```
 ->having('distances', '<', 32.688888])
```

to

```
->having('distances', '<', [32.688888])
```

and

```
->join('locations as l', 'l.id', '=', 'users. location_id')
```

to

```
->join('locations as l', 'users.location_id', '=', 'l.id')
```

Final Query:

**Edit**

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('locations as l', 'users.location_id', '=', 'l.id')
            ->select('users.*', DB::raw('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(22.559648)) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lng`) - radians(88.415552)) + sin(radians(22.559648)) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) as distances'))
            ->having('distances', '<', 32.688888)
            ->orderBy('distances', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```